How can I call LAMMPS from a Python script multiple times in paralllel?
I'm working on a Python program that needs to call multiple LAMMPS runs and extract some computes. The code looks something like this:
from lammps import lammps, LMP_STYLE_GLOBAL, LMP_STYLE_SCALAR
from mpi4py import MPI
...
def lammps_run():
   comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
   lmp = lammps()
   eng = lmp.extract_compute("thermo_pe", LMP_STYLE_GLOBAL, LMP_STYLE_SCALAR)
   ...
   return computes...

something = lammps_run()
...
something2 = lammps_run()
...

And when I run mpirun -np N python script.py I face problems like Exception: ERROR: Energy was not tallied on needed timestep (src/compute_pe.cpp:88), or the software suddenly stops without error messages, or with mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated. Does anyone knows what I can do to fix that?
Additional information: The problem with Energy was not tallied on needed timestep doesn't exist when I run in serial, and I've tried using pylammpsmpi but it was worse than running in serial. When I call lammps_run() only one time the code seems to work fine in serial and parallel.

You can write to me at my email address (You can find it from my profile) or by searching my name. I have a Python script which does this and can share it with you.

If the instances run independently of each other, is organizing them as iterable object (e.g., a list) and subsequent work with this pool with Python's multiprocessing an alternative suitable for you?

@Buttonwood, the instances need to run sequentially for my purposes, so the only solution is to run every step in parallel.
